# magit-diff jumps to insertion/deletion in already opened window (no overlay)

Tags: magit, buffers, window, diff

I have 2 windows open: One is the magit-diff of the current repo, the other is just source codes from that repo. In source codes (the right window), I have a file opened, say "sample.txt". In magit-diff (the left window), I can see all of the deletion and insertion that occur for "sample.txt". In other words, it looks like this:

```
    | magit-diff                    | "sample.txt  |
    | modified sample.txt           |              |
    | + text I added                |              | 
    | - text I removed              |              |
```

Now, if I press enter on the line "+ text I removed", then I would be taken straight to "sample.txt" at the exact line where the insertion/deletion happens.  The only problem is that this would open another buffer that overlays the current magit-diff buffer.  The original window for "sample.txt" does not change. In other words:

```
    | "sample.txt"                                    | "sample.txt" |
    | cursor at line of inseration/deletion           |              |
    |                                                 |              | 
    |                                                 |              |
```

I do not want this to happen.  What I want is once I press enter in magit-diff, I would like the other window (the right window with "sample.txt" already opened) to jump to the line of insertion/deletion. If "sample.txt" is not already opened yet, then just open the file in another window. In other words, after pressing enter:

```
    | magit-diff                    | "sample.txt"                                     |
    | modified sample.txt           |  cursor at line of insertion/deletion            |
    | + text I added                |                                                  | 
    | - text I removed              |                                                  |
```

Is there a way to do this within emacs? Please let me know and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The option `magit-display-buffer` allows you to control in great detail how buffers are displayed.